# Find the minimum number of subspaces of max. dimension $k$ to cover finite field $\mathbb{F}_q^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces, finite-fields

My question is the following: assume a vector space of dimension $n$ over a finite field of size $q$, that is $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. Let $ 1 < k < n$. I would like to find the minimum number of subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ of dimension *at most* $k$ that could cover all elements of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. To be more concrete, let $\mathcal{V} = \{V_1, ... , V_T \}$ be a set of subspaces $V_i \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q^n$ where $dim(V_i) \leq k$ for all $i = 1, ... , T$ and $V_1 \cup ... \cup V_T = \mathbb{F}_q^n$. Then I would like to find the minimum possible value of $T$ to be able to construct such a set $\mathcal{V}$.

A very similar question is the one answered in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316577900012). However, they allow the use of $k$-flats, which could be cosets of subspaces. In my question, I'm more constrained in the sense that I only allow subspaces.

Comment: Do you really mean $V_1 + \dots + V_T = \mathbb{F}_q^n$ or perhaps $V_1 \cup \dots \cup V_T = \mathbb{F}_q^n$?

Comment: You are right, I meant the union. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a complete answer is given in the paper

> [Apoorva Khare,
>   Vector spaces as unions of proper subspaces. 
>   Linear Algebra Appl. 431 (2009), no. 9, 1681–1686.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2746.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Thank you so much for the much-needed pointer!

Comment: You're welcome. The article was a discovery for me as well. The guy's good, and the paper is sharp and well written.